# Name for ratio of three co-linear points in affine geometry

Tags: notation, terminology, affine-geometry

Given three points $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ in an affine space such that $\dim \langle a_1, a_2, a_3\rangle = 1$ (i.e. they are co-linear) and $a_1\ne a_2$, my professor defined the "simple ratio" (making a literal translation) as the unique scalar
$$
(a_1a_2a_3) := \lambda \in\mathbb{K} \qquad\text{such that}\qquad \overrightarrow{a_1a_3}=\lambda\, \overrightarrow{a_1a_2}\,.
$$

I haven't found any equivalent term in English sources. Is such a concept defined in other places, or does it happen to be "popular" where I live?

For example, this notation is used in "Álgebra Lineal i Geometria" by M. Castellet and I. Llerena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia [Projective harmonic conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_harmonic_conjugate) article uses the term "division ratio" which is rare in English unfortunately. More precisely, it states "C divides AB externally" and gives the ratio $AC:BC$ which corresponds to your $\lambda$ and where $ABC$ are three points in order on a line. A third point can divide a line segment "internally" where the ratio $\lambda$ is negative. Further it also states:

> In terms of a double ratio, given points a and b on an affine line, the division ratio of a point x is $$ t(x)=\frac  {x-a}{x-b}.$$

It seems to me that the term "division ratio" is what you want, although "simple ratio" is simpler.

Comment: Please see my reference to Coxeter's book. I must admit that I am more familiar with Russian terminology, where the adjective "simple" is used instead.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I've ever seen this affine version named before, but I have seen the projective geometry concept that it's a case of: the [cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio)
$$(a_4,a_1;a_2,a_3) = \frac{a_1a_3\cdot a_4a_2}{a_1a_2\cdot a_4a_3}$$
 If we choose $a_4$ to be the point at $\infty$ on the line, then $\frac{a_4a_3}{a_4a_2}=1$ and this becomes $\frac{a_1a_3}{a_1a_2}=\lambda$.

Comment: The cross ratio is an invariant in Projective Geometry (simple ratio is not invariant there, and you need a ratio of ratios). Observe that the cross ratio is a ratio of simple ratios.

Answer (score 1):

Ratios between segments are preserved in Affine Geometry. The simple ratio is not just popular, it has been widely used. Sometimes they define it a bit differently (instead of $A_1A_3/A_1A_2$ you take, for example, $A_1A_3/A_2A_3$. All of those are related, and what is more important, all these are preserved under affine transformations. BTW, Castellet and Llerena is a great book!

Comment: For example, the midpoint divides the segment in a simple ratio =2, according with your definition. The midpoint is an affine invariant.

Comment: Do you have a reference for it being named in English?

Comment: I was a bit surprised not to find the term "simple ratio" as often as expected. But  you can check, for example, Coxeter's book (a classic) https://books.google.com/books?id=usKZpDAH0WUC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%22simple+ratio%22+three+points+affine+coxeter&source=bl&ots=t-Sydx5-nO&sig=ACfU3U2eIY5iUIZh0xpaZYwh24C_6WyGrA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYx-PMj8LgAhUEVN8KHUzqBW0Q6AEwCXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22simple%20ratio%22%20three%20points%20affine%20coxeter&f=false